# Can't connect to local SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, ado.net, enterprise-library

I'm trying to call a sproc from EntLib (MVC3, EntLib5, SQL Server 2008). I'm using the default instance of SQL Server and can connect to it just fine from SQL Server Management Studio. I've tried everything I could find online and nothing gets me connected. The service is running as LocalSystem. Here's the connecction string:

Server=local;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=True

Here's the error message I'm getting:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Now, it seems to be caching "local." How do I force it to read the new server name?

Comment: You have to close and restart your application. Maybe recycle the application pool in IIS for good measure (assuming you're using IIS and not Cassini, the built-in VS web server).

Comment: Even after a reboot, it still seems to be returning a cached result. I did verify that your suggested server name allows me to connect to the db via EntLib. This is how I'm trying to read the connection string:

ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Const.ConnectionString].ConnectionString;

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening. Application settings aren't cached -- once your application is recycled it will re-read the settings. Are you using web.config transformations? Do you have the connection string hard-coded or set in multiple places? What if you hard-code the connection string into your code instead of reading it from the Configuration manager?

Comment: I found the problem. There are 3 config files: Web.config, Web.Debug.config, and Web.Release.Config. I was fiddling with the Web.Debug.config, but the app is reading from Web.config. Hmmm...I guess I'll have to read up on that. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: If you're debugging (if you click the Debug button from within Visual Studio), it will use whatever's in Web.config. If you *publish* your application set in Debug configuration, it will use Web.Debug.config, and if you *publish* your application set in Release configuration, it will use Web.Release.config. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server should be "localhost", not "local", and the "TCP/IP" and "Named Pipes" protocols should be enabled in SQL Server Configuration Manager. Also, if you want to use a trusted connection, you might need to enable Windows Authentication on your MVC3 application, otherwise provide a username and password in the connection string as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with your local SQL Server you need to use localhost or "."